# Profiling Firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, profiling

Any suggestions on tools to use to profile Firefox addon written in Javascript? Hopefully one that works with the latest Firefox.

While on that topic, any suggestions on tools to use to debug Firefox addon? Chromebug is no longer maintained.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=profile+javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM_Inspector

Comment: Thanks. Following the links mentioned above, I reached [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Performance/Profiling_with_the_Built-in_Profiler) which seems promising. I haven't tried it yet though.  However still looking for good recommendation for debugging Firefox addon. DOM Inspector doesn't really cut it.

Comment: What specifically are you after in terms of debugging? I usually use either https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.utils.reportError or https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIConsoleService coupled with the Console² (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/console%C2%B2/) extension to find where my code is breaking. Also, although the DOM Inspector addon is a bit old and clunky, it still seems to do the job IMHO.

Comment: I am looking for a true debugger (setting breakpoints, inspecting variables, etc), rather than 'printf' debugging (for lack of better word). Looking through Firefox code base seems a Chrome debugger is on it's way. Currently it's disabled as it still not complete.

Comment: Maybe try Venkman. It's a little old, but I think it still works ok with the latest Firefox. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-debugger/

Comment: Also, the JS debugger api might be of use to you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/JS_Debugger_API_Reference